# How to remove Vimeo logo in embed album

Tags: vimeo

I have a Vimeo plus account. I can remove the Vimeo logo from a single video but I cannot remove it from a playlist. I looked for a solution on Google but couldn't find one. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. I was told by their support agent that you can not remove the "vimeo" logo from an embedded playlist. but that it was a something they would pass up to the feature request team. For what thats worth.